# Shouldn't Backgroundworker avoid main windows freeze?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, backgroundworker, office-addins

I am trying to test the Backgroundworker for an Office Add-In. The simple code is like this :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Ribbon1
Dim f As New Form1
Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker


Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(New WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext())
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    For x = 1 To 100
        f.Label1.Text = x.ToString
    Next
    f.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

I understand the backgroundworker as a tool which can run together with the main application. But the main application freezes (or is disabled) until the backgroundworker has finished its work. Is this normal ?

Comment: in DoWork, you can't reference this `f.Label1.Text` that requires accessing the UI thread. If you want to update the UI, you have to do it in the background worker ProgressChanged event

Comment: If you'd [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you would have seen : `You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.`.  This is rule zero of using threads - *don't touch the UI*.

Comment: Looks like problem solved - don't call UI elements in `DoWork`- use BGW events for it

Answer (score 1):

An invoke is required if cross thread access is there.
And there is no requirement for `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(New WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext())`

Do something like this.

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    For x = 1 To 100
        Me.Invoke(Sub() f.Label1.Text = x.ToString)
    Next
    Me.Invoke(Sub() f.Show())
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers